# I'm not sure how this works, never seen such an operator "= -"

Tags: logic, operators, bitwise-operators, addition, binary-operators

I was reading someone's code and found out that he wrote the code (below following).
for example:

```
operandA = -operandA;
```

That works but I don't understand how this operator is working. Can anyone give any similar idea please?

In the program's logic, the given statement changes the movement of X (operandA) to reverse direction  when it hits something.

Comment: This is equivalent to `operandA = -1*operandA;` which seems logical to reverse a direction

Comment: Yeah, exactly! Thank you, appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is just setting operandA to the negative of operandA